# Combining bar and line chart with numerical and categorical variables with ggplot R

Tags: r, ggplot2, bar-chart, categorical-data, continuous

I'm trying to combine a bar plot and line plot in ggplot using continuous and categorical variables. I basically need to do something like this:

[image]

So far I've got this code:

```
ggplot(data=nutrients, aes(x=Plot, y=Level, fill=Factor)) +
         geom_bar(stat="identity", position = 'dodge', colour="black")
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

```
ggplot(mtcars, aes(x = factor(cyl), y = wt, fill = factor(gear))) + 
    geom_bar(stat = "identity", position = "dodge") +
    geom_line(aes(y = ave(wt, cyl, FUN = max), group = gear)) + 
    geom_point(aes(y = ave(wt, cyl, FUN = max), group = gear))
```

Change the `FUN` as necessary

[image]

Comment: Thanks a lot d.b. I have tried your suggestion and now I have got this.  
ggplot(nutrients, aes(x = Plot, y = Level, fill = Factor)) + 
    geom_bar(stat = "identity", position = "dodge") +
    geom_line(aes(y = ave(Level, Plot, FUN = min), group = Factor)) + 
    geom_point(aes(y = ave(Level, Plot, FUN = min), group = Factor))                         
I am wondering if there is a chance to move the scale - from 6 to 6.5 to the right hand side.